# Codeigniter - Two images upload did not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I tried to upload two images using a form. To do that I wrote a image function.

```
protected function imageUploadResize($filename, $field_name, $width, $height, $maker){
    // thumb image upload settings
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/packages/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    // thumb upload settings
    $image_new_name = time().'_'.$filename;                    
    $config['file_name'] = $image_new_name; 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    // upload thumb image
    if ( $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {
        // resize uploaded file
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/packages/'.$image_new_name;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']         = $width;
        $config['height']       = $height;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = $maker;
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();    

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());                   
    } else {
       $imageData = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }  
    return $image_new_name;
}
```

And I access that function this way,

```
// allocate image name to data set
if(!empty($_FILES["thumb_image"]['name'])){
    // thumb upload
    $thumb_image_new_name = $this->imageUploadResize($_FILES["thumb_image"]['name'],'thumb_image',THUMB_IMAGE_WIDTH, THUMB_IMAGE_HEIGHT, '_thumb');                    
    $data['thumb_image'] = $thumb_image_new_name;
}else{
    $data['thumb_image'] = "";
}
// allocate image name to data set
if(!empty($_FILES["banner_image"]['name'])){
    // banner upload
    $banner_image_new_name = $this->imageUploadResize($_FILES["banner_image"]['name'],'banner_image',BANNER_IMAGE_WIDTH, BANNER_IMAGE_HEIGHT, '_banner');                    
    $data['banner_image'] = $banner_image_new_name;
}else{
    $data['banner_image'] = "";
}
```

When I upload one image (thumb_image or banner_image) above function is worked properly.

But when I upload both images thumb_image uploaded properly but banner_image did not upload properly. As a example assume I am going to upload Hydrangeas.jpg and Desert.jpg. Then it is working this way,

**Then file uploaded this way (images names of the folder),**

- 1493025280_Hydrangeas.jpg
- 1493025280_Hydrangeas_thumb.jpg
- 1493025280_Hydrangeas1.jpg - image name also wrong

**But expected output is (images names of the folder),**

- 1493025280_Hydrangeas.jpg
- 1493025280_Hydrangeas_thumb.jpg
- 1493025280_Desert.jpg
- 1493025280_Desert_banner.jpg

Can someone please help me, thank you..

Comment: Can i suggest you a whole different approach?

Comment: @satafaka yes please

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, add a comment and i will try to help you more with your code.

Answer (score 3):

A different approach that i use for file uploads is below.
I rearrange the $_FILES array because the original has some difficulties with keys and objects.

```
$files = array();
   foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $num_key => $dummy) {
      foreach ($_FILES['files'] as $txt_key => $dummy) {
         $files[$num_key][$txt_key] = $_FILES['files'][$txt_key][$num_key];
      }
   }
```

In new array, loop through each image and do what you need:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file['error'] == 0) {
          //Your code here...
          //Call your function imageUploadResize
    }
}
```

Comment: Although its plain php , not the CI upload way, but it is always useful and it always works. My upvote

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution, In codeigniter when upload image, we have to call,

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Then we have to initialized the configurations.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

And when resize image we have to call,

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

Then have to initialized the configurations.

```
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

Therefore completed function is,

```
protected function imageUploadResize($filename, $field_name, $width, $height, $maker){
    // thumb image upload settings
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/packages/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    // thumb upload settings
    $image_new_name = time().'_'.$filename;                    
    $config['file_name'] = $image_new_name; 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    // upload thumb image
    if ( $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {
        // resize uploaded file
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = './uploads/packages/'.$image_new_name;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']         = $width;
        $config['height']       = $height;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = $maker;
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize(); 

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());                   
    } else {
       $imageData = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }  
    return $image_new_name;
}
```